# Converting int to string in java is giving the answer as 1

Tags: java, string, binary, int

I converted a decimal integer to binary and that binary integer when I'm trying to convert to a string is giving me 1 as the answer always when it should give the value of the string.

```
         while(a>0) 
         {
             b = a%2;
             n = b;
             a = a/2;
         System.out.print(n);
         }

        String m = Integer.toString(n);
         System.out.print(m);
```

Any corrections and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you were expecting to see, the word 'one' ??

Comment: I think you want n += b instead of n = b

Comment: @ControlAltDel That will give you the bitCount().

Comment: ```String m = Integer.toString(a, 2); System.out.print(m);```

Comment: @smoggers I'm trying to say, for eg if I take a=13, I'm getting n=1011 as the output (which is in reverse but thats the issue right now). So, when I'm converting this integer value n to string, instead of showing "1011" its giving me 1 as the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On every loop step, you have these two statements:

```
b = a % 2;
n = b;
```

Think about why all the possible values of `n` are `0` and `1`?

It's because `n` copies the value of `b`, which is the value of `a modulo 2`, which is always `0` or `1`.

The last value of `n` will be the left-most bit of the binary representation of `a`, which will be always `1` (unless `a` is `0`) and this is why you always get `1` when printing `m`.

Comment: So basically just the last value of n is getting stored? Alright, got the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you use

```
n = b;
```

you are replacing the value of n each time.  What you want it to accumulate the bits in n.  The simplest way to do this is to use a StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (a > 0) {
    int lowest = a & 1;
    sb.insert(0, lowest);
    a = a >>> 1; // shift the bits down by 1.
}

String m = sb.toString();
System.out.print(m);
```

This will do the same thing as `Integer.toString(a, 2)`